# React - Loads of useless network requests containing export default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web

I have a folder structure with a lot of images and I have a script that compiles the relative paths to an index file during the build, which I then could reference in the code programatically.

Currently, these index files look like this and sit alongside the images:

```
import file0 from "./IMG_6126.jpg";
import file0min from "./IMG_6126MIN.jpg";
import file1 from "./IMG_6139.jpg";
import file1min from "./IMG_6139MIN.jpg";
export const LPP_2022_07_09 = [
  {
    url: file0,
    minUrl: file0min,
    height: 3407,
    width: 6000,
    dateTaken: new Date(),
  },
  {
    url: file1,
    minUrl: file1min,
    height: 4000,
    width: 5281,
    dateTaken: new Date(),
  }
];
```

I can then use the index file like this

```
import { LPP_2022_07_09 } from "../Collections/London/LPP 2022-07-09";

export const Album = () =>
  LPP_2022_07_09.map((i) => <img src={i.minUrl} />);
```

However, this makes a **request for every image** [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFJe0.png) regardless if it's used in the current component tree or not.

This already takes more than a second to parse through just running locally. The request response is just `export default //url//'. I tried using default exports but the same thing happened. What is going on here?

Comment: So why not just require them on demand using a function instead of storing the imports in memory?

Comment: @JBallin Because if I add, say, a new collection with a few albums, I will have to update the imports. But I want so that I could do something like Collections.flatmap(c => c.albums.map(i => <img src={i}/>)) and thus I would not need to change the code, just rebuild.